# Trigger a div on an external button/<a> click on slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I have used a `Slick Slider` on my page. Now, everything works fine, but I have to make the particular div triggered on a specific button press. It is like if I have `div-2`, and I have a button named as `button-2` somewhere in the section, on click of it, the slick slider should change it to the div 2, making it active with the right active slick dots.

I have researched about it and got to know that [sliderGoTo](https://gist.github.com/galdiolo/4b73c81925f659320b5a) will do my job. But I don't know why it is not working fine. I have tried my level best, but somehow the button doesn't trigger the right div at all.

What I have tried so far (in pseudo form):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').slick({
    dots: true,
    arrows: false
  });

  $('#trigger-button').click(function() {
      slideIndex = $(this).index();
      $('.slideshow').slickGoTo(parseInt(slideIndex));
    )
  }
});

/*$('#trigger-button').click(function() {
  var slider = $('.box');
  slider[1].slickGoTo(parseInt(actIndex));
})*/ 

//Alternatively used
```

```html
<a class='btn' id='trigger-button' href='#'>Button 2</a>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='div-1'>
    Some content
  </div>
  <div class='div-2'>
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this also, since I want the specific div to be triggered that is `div-2`, to be triggered when we press the button with the id `trigger-button`. Can be found as the comment.

But no results. I don't have much experience with usage of **SLICK SLIDER**, but I have tried. I would be glad to learn more about it. Thanks

**EDITS**

Thank You guys for helping me out. I have found one solution for me, and that too in an easier way. If you want to go to a specific pos, you have to use this syntax and your work is done :

`$('.box').slick('slickGoTo', divNo)`. Remember divNo = currentPos - 1.

Nowadays, the `slickGoTo` doesn't work like the previous syntax which is `.slickGoTo(parseInt(slideIndex));`. It will give you an error which is `Undefined slickGoTo method`. Proper usage is depicted in my code. Thanks again, and I'm sure this will help people in future references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$('.box').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex), false);` instead.

On a side note: I'm not sure using `.index()` will always work as intended.

Check https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You have some error in your code.How you can get the index of element is depends upon your elements on HTML

But currently you have to `div` so you can set `index` as 1 and increment/reset `onclick` of button.

**Replace**

```
$('#trigger-button').click(function() {
      slideIndex = $(this).index();
      $('.slideshow').slickGoTo(parseInt(slideIndex));
    )
  }
```

**To**

```
var indexVal=1;  $("#trigger-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       // slideIndex = $(this).index();
        $( '.box' ).slickGoTo(indexVal);
        indexVal=indexVal+1;
        if(indexVal>2){
        indexVal=1;
        } });
```

**Here is a working snippet for you:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").slick({
        dots: true,
    arrows: false
    });

});
var indexVal=1;
 $("#trigger-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       // slideIndex = $(this).index();
        $( '.box' ).slickGoTo(indexVal);
        indexVal=indexVal+1;
        if(indexVal>2){
        indexVal=1;
        }
    });

/*$('#trigger-button').click(function() {
  var slider = $('.box');
  slider[1].slickGoTo(parseInt(actIndex));
})*/ 

//Alternatively used
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.min.js"/></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.css"/>

<a class='btn' id='trigger-button' href='#'>Button 2</a>


<div class='box'>
  <div class='div-1'>
    Some content1
  </div>
  <div class='div-2'>
    Some content2
  </div>
</div>
```